# SQL datetime2(7) field to Django

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I need to rewrite this SQL column to a django model field

```
DateCreated (datetime2(7), not null)
```

what does the datetime2(7) exactly translate to?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an SQL server database?

Comment: Yes SQL server 14

Comment: @iklinac: I think the focus is here what Django model field maps to the `datetim2(7)`

Comment: His question is more in a terms of what datetime2(7) exactly translate to, so not really Django related in my personal opinion. But I can see your angle on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [**`django-mssql-backend`** package [GitHub]](https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend), then it is a [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField), based on the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/blob/7982506f0bb012aa10f28e2825343f1267172241/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py#L79):

> ```
> data_types = {
>     # ...,
>     'DateTimeField': 'datetime2',
>     # …
> }
> ```

This will thus translate to a `datetime2` column type, and the [default precision is seven [ms-doc]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Precision, scale, 0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The **default precision is 7 digits**.